Assistance in third phase diagram of the pressure-composition and temperature curve in the metal hydride for lanthanum penta nickel hydride
Using the following research paper, I am trying to do the analytical calculations for the $\ce{LaNi5}$.
Link: https://doi.org/10.1016/0360-3199(94)90097-3
I am trying to plot the third phase diagram in the PCT curve also known as the beta-phase, I am using the following equation for the plot.
$\mathrm{C_H = A P^{\gamma/2}\exp(\frac{-\gamma \Delta H}{RT})\exp(\frac{-\gamma P V_H}{RT})}$
Where, $\mathrm{V_H}$ represents the molar volume of the hydrogen, $\mathrm{\gamma}$ represents the activity coefficient, and also A which represents the coefficient.
I would like to know how I can calculate the activity coefficient for the hydrogen above the equilibrium pressure of 1.49 atm for the $\ce{LaNi_5}$, and how I can predict the molar volume of the hydrogen and also the coefficient A in the equation.
